# Resize image when pasted to RichTextBox - or another solution?

Tags: vb.net, image, resize, richtextbox

I have a Windows form with a TabControl. In Tab 1 I have a RichTextBox (rtb1) and a Picturebox (pbx). In Tab 2 I have another RichTextBox (rtb2).

When I click a button, text from rtb1 and the current picture in pbx is put into rtb2. Problem is that the picturesize won't always fit. My current code is this:

```
        Dim text = rtb1.Text
        rtb2.AppendText(text)
        Clipboard.SetImage(pbx.Image)
        rtb2.Paste()
```

Is it possible to have the code resize the image as it's pasted?

It is possible to get the image from a windows path, I just didn't know how to resize this in a RichTextBox either. If this makes it easier?

Edit: This did it!

```
        Dim newWidth = 500
        Dim newHeight = 500
        Clipboard.SetImage(New Bitmap(pbxDatasheet.Image, newWidth, newHeight))
        rtbArmy.Paste()
```

Edit 2: It still doesn't work.

With the exact same code these things happen:
1. Most of the time the pasted picture(s) are the same size. But not the right size. I can change newWidth and newHeight all I want, they rarely differ in size. Although sometimes the picture is way larger than the others.
2. Sometimes it doesn't even add the picture to the RichTextBox. There's no pattern to when it happens.

The same lines of code can do all the above things. I have no idea what to do here.

Comment: `Clipboard.SetImage(new Bitmap(pbx.Image, newWidth, newHeight))`. Of course, you should calculate the correct scale.

Comment: It tags `Bitmap` with an error: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments."
And lists 5 different types that can't be converted.

Yes, the actual size should be easy later.

Comment: Well, you did *something wrong*. [This is the overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Drawing_Image_System_Int32_System_Int32_) of the Bitmap constructor that accepts those arguments (it's also quite common). You should pay attention to what arguments you're passing there.

Comment: I got it to work now. Thanks! Is it possible to have it autoscale if only putting in width, for example?

Comment: I got the solution myself with some simple math.

`        Dim height = pbx.Image.Height
        Dim width = pbx.Image.Width
        Dim factor = width / 500 ' Or any other number that fits the wanted the width.

        Dim newWidth = 500 ' Again, any other number.
        Dim newHeight = height / factor`

Comment: Yes, all right. A common way to is: `scale = [New Width] / [Original Width] -> [New Size] = new Size(CInt([Original Width] * scale), CInt([Original Height] * scale))`

Comment: Now I get another problem. It isn't consistent in the sizing of the picture. Sometimes it resizes it, sometimes it doesn't (even with the same picture). This is really weird. 

And sometimes it doesn't even add the picture. I know there's nothing random when coding. The problem must be at my end, but it does look random from my current point of view.